# why do i get could not resolve host error on cmd?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In the process of making my Spring Boot application restful, I was following a tutorial from the Spring Boot site and I encountered this problem on the command prompt when I run
the command:

```
curl -v localhost:8080/employees/1 | json_pp
```

Then I get:

> could not find host:json_pp

[image]

I was trying trying to make my JSON pretty following the Spring Boot tutorial on the Spring site but when I ran this command I got the *could not find host: json_pp*

Comment: The pipe symbol (i.e. `|`) does not appear in the screen capture.